# How to maintain the multiple arrays in react state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to making the product varients and attributes in react. I had appended the rows on click. My row have the following fields.

Name `{textbox}` -> like Size, color

Type `{select tag}` -> static things like slide size

Value `{textbox}` -> Needed an array. The increase in value the increase in varients. Means the varients will directly depends on the value.

For e.g.: 
If I add the Name "Color" and give the value to Black(#000) it have the one product with color black.

If I add the new row and add the Name "Size" and set its value to "XL" then it makes the varient with color black and size XL. If I add the new size "XXL" to existing row then it will make another varient

At that time I have two varients

1. size "XL" and color "Black"
2. size "XXL" and color "Black"

I try to maintain this in a single array. But when I set the state it makes the prev key undefined.

state

```
rows: [{
    name:'', type: '', attribute: ''
}]
```

Change event

```
handleChange = idx => e => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    const rows = [...this.state.rows];
    rows[idx] = { 
        [name]: value
    };
    this.setState({
        rows
    });
};
```

Add row

```
handleAddRow = () => {
    var item = {
      name: "",
      type: "",
      attribute: ""
    };
    this.setState({
      rows: [...this.state.rows, item]
    });
};
```

map function for rows

```
{ 
    this.state.rows.map((item, idx) => (
    <tr id={idx} key={idx}>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="name"
                   value={this.state.rows[idx].name}
                   onChange={this.handleChange(idx)}
                   className="form-control" />
        </td>
        ...
    ...
```

I need to maintain the following JSON in state

```
[
    {
        "name": Color,
        "type": color,
        "value": [
            {
                "name": black,
                "value": #000 
            }
        ]
    },
    {
    "name": Size,
    "type": size,
    "value": [
        {
            "name": XXL,
            "name": Xl,
            "name": L, 
        }
    ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following this immutable update pattern to properly update an object in an array :

```
handleChange = idx => e => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    this.setState(prevState => ({
        rows: prevState.rows.map((row, index) => {
            if (index !== idx) {
              return row;
            }
            return { 
              ...row,
              [name]: value
            }
        })
    }));
};
```

Comment: Thanks It works..
Now I am trying to set the nested objects in the "value". I had setup the onKeyUp function and also checked the it puts the value in array only on enter. Now it Changes it's previous value with the new one instead of making a new object.

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention at this, you cannot have twice the same key in a object:

```
value": [
      {
        "name": XXL,
        "name": Xl,
        "name": L, 
      }
    ]
```

You should turn it in:

```
value": [
          "XXL",
          "Xl",
          "L", 
        ]
```

or in:

```
value": [
          {
            "name": "XXL",
          },
          { 
            "name": "Xl",
          },
          {
            "name": "L", 
          },
        ]
```

Answer (score 0):

A few issues with your code. First if your new state depends on the current state use functional form of `setState`. Also your rendering method is a bit off:

```
 handleChange = e => {    // No need for a nested func here
  const { name, value } = e.target;

  this.setState(state => ({      // Functional form of setState
    rows: [...state.rows, { [name]: value }]
  }));
};

handleAddRow = () => {
  var item = {
    name: "",
    type: "",
    attribute: ""
  };
  this.setState(state => ({
    // Functional form of setState
    rows: [...state.rows, item]
  }));
};


// Mapping
{ 
   this.state.rows.map((item, idx) => (
   <tr id={idx} key={idx}>
   <td>
    <input type="text" name="name"
     value={item.name}                      // Just use item here
     onChange={this.handleChange}           // Do no call a function here
     className="form-control" />
   </td>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your state is Object Or array then you can update state like below code

```
 this.state = {
            form: {
                email: {
                    value: null,
                    error: null,
                    isRequired: true,
                    isValid: false,
                    extraValidation: 'email'
                },
                password: {
                    value: null,
                    error: null,
                    isRequired: true,
                    isValid: false,
                }
            },
        }

    handleChange(value, key) {
        let form = { ...this.state.form }
        form[key].error = null;
        form[key].value = value;
        this.setState({ form });
    }
```